# Why is $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}((t))$ transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$?

Tags: fields, power-series, local-fields

Why is $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}((t))$ transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ ?

I guess $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}((t))$ is not unramified over $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$ because $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}((t))$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$・・・①.

But why ① holds? I couldn't check ① by myself.
What element is transcendental element? And why?  (In general, to prove transcendentality exactly is difficult, is it managable in this case?)

Comment: Consider $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty c_n t^n$, where $c_n$ generates $\mathbb F_{p^n}$.

Comment: How to prove the element is transcendental ?